# Minimizing expected mutual distances in spherical regions

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, spherical-geometry, isoperimetric-problems

Suppose I take the unit sphere in $d$ dimensions, and I take some subset $A$ of the sphere of fixed relative volume $V$. Now from this set $A$ I draw two vectors, uniformly at random, and I look at their mutual distance (or angle). Depending on the shape of $A$, the pairwise distances obtained from this process may be very large or very small.

My intuition says that if we want to minimize the expected value of the pairwise distances, or if we want to maximize the probability of getting a distance below some threshold, then the best shape for $A$ is always a spherical cap, i.e. all vectors on the sphere with first coordinate larger than some parameter $\alpha$.

Can this be proven? Has something similar been shown before? Or can anyone provide references or appropriate keywords to search for, to find relevant literature on this topic?

Comment: You are looking for optima of $\int V(|x-y|)d\mu(x)d\mu(y)$ over (in your case, uniform) measures $\mu$. I found this kind of question is usually the domain of something called "potential theory" by practitioners. Hopefully this is a useful keyword.

Comment: I think all you need is a spherical version of Riesz rearrangement inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_rearrangement_inequality), like theorem 1.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.06813v1